# Mudança de temas através do Java

Tags: java, android, mobile

Olá! Tenho um código em java onde gostaria de trocar os temas do AndroidManifest de acordo com o retorno de determinada função.

Exemplo:
Tendo uma função booleana que verifique a conexão com a internet, a atividade usará um tema quando a função for verdadeira e outro quando a função for falsa.

```
<style name="TemaVerdadeiro" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="TemaFalso" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/branco</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/branco</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/ERRO</item>
</style>
```

Existe algum comando que possa escolher esses temas de acordo com a condição escolhida?

Answer (score 1):

Para atribuir o tema a uma Activity use o método [setTheme()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setTheme(int)).

Tenha em conta que o novo tema tem de ser atribuído no método `onCreate()` e antes de `setContentView()`.

```
@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if(temInternet()){
        setTheme(R.style.TemaVerdadeiro);
    }
    else{
        setTheme(R.style.TemaFalso);
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity);

    ......
    ......

}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, será bem útil.

Teria alguma forma de fazer isso após o setContentView()? (Digo, durante a execução da atividade)