# Como mudar atributos de todas as TextViews do projeto em tempo de execução?

Tags: java, android, xml

Estou implementando uma seção de configurações visuais de um projeto e umas das configurações deve permitir que o usuário possa mudar a fontFamily de todo os textos, também há a opção de deixar todos os textos maiúsculos ou minúsculos.
Eu sei que é possível deixar um textView maiúsculo usando o textAllCaps, mas não encontrei nada sobre a fontFamily, tampouco sobre como aplicar essas configurações em todo o projeto.
Existe alguma forma de resolver esse problema?
Grato desde já.

O projeto ainda não tem nada pronto em relação a mudança de todas as textViews, pois não sei como devo fazer isso. Mas vou deixar os código da Activity de configurações.

XML da Activity de configurações:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_back"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/purple_right_rounded_backgroud"
            android:onClick="backToMainScreen"
            android:padding="4dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline8"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline18"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_revert" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView19"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="CONFIGURAÇÕES"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:fontFamily="casual" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/yellow_mustard"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView30"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/background_maincolor_dark"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Tipo de letra"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:fontFamily="casual" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="4dp">

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/rgLetterType"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:background="@drawable/white_rounded_backgroud">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb_casual"
                    android:layout_width="110dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="CASUAL" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb_cursiva"
                    android:layout_width="110dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="CURSIVA" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb_bastao"
                    android:layout_width="110dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="BASTÃO" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb_imprensa"
                    android:layout_width="110dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="IMPRENSA" />

            </RadioGroup>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView32"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Visualização:"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView31"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="4dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    app:fontFamily="casual" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/yellow_mustard"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/otherConfigs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/background_maincolor_dark"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Outros ajustes"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:fontFamily="casual" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="4dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView21"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="As letras devem ser:"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/rgLetterCase"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:background="@drawable/white_rounded_backgroud"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb_uppercase"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="MAIÚSCULA" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb_lowercase"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="MINÚSCULA" />

            </RadioGroup>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Controller da Activity de configurações:

package com.example.anaplb.appalpha.activities;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;

import com.example.anaplb.appalpha.R;
import com.example.anaplb.appalpha.config.AppConfig;

public class ConfigActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private AppConfig configurator;
    private RadioGroup rgLetterType;
    private RadioButton rbCasual;
    private RadioButton rbCursiva;
    private RadioButton rbBastao;
    private RadioButton rbImprensa;

```
private RadioGroup rgLetterCase;
private RadioButton rbUpper;
private RadioButton rbLower;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_config);

    this.rgLetterType = findViewById(R.id.rgLetterType);
    this.rgLetterCase = findViewById(R.id.rgLetterCase);
    this.rbCasual = findViewById(R.id.rb_casual);
    this.rbCursiva = findViewById(R.id.rb_cursiva);
    this.rbBastao = findViewById(R.id.rb_bastao);
    this.rbImprensa = findViewById(R.id.rb_imprensa);
    this.rbUpper = findViewById(R.id.rb_uppercase);
    this.rbLower = findViewById(R.id.rb_lowercase);

    this.configurator = AppConfig.getInstance(getApplicationContext());


}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    loadConfigsInView();
}

public void backToMainScreen(View view){
    finish();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    pushChanges();
    this.configurator.saveAllChange(getApplicationContext());
}

private void pushChanges(){
    String rgSelectedLetterType =((RadioButton)findViewById(this.rgLetterType.getCheckedRadioButtonId())).getText().toString();
    String rgSelectedLetterCase =((RadioButton)findViewById(this.rgLetterCase.getCheckedRadioButtonId())).getText().toString();
    this.configurator.setCurrentLetterType(rgSelectedLetterType);
    this.configurator.setCurrentLetterCase(rgSelectedLetterCase);
}

private void loadConfigsInView(){
    Log.i("Json-Config","Entrou em LoadConfigs");
    Log.i("Json-Config","CurrentLetterType: " + this.configurator.getCurrentLetterType());
    Log.i("Json-Config","CurrentLetterCase: " + this.configurator.getCurrentLetterCase());
    switch(this.configurator.getCurrentLetterType()){
        case(AppConfig.CASUAL):
            rgLetterType.check(rbCasual.getId());
            Log.i("Json-Config","CASUAL");
        break;

        case(AppConfig.CURSIVA):
            rgLetterType.check(rbCursiva.getId());

            Log.i("Json-Config","CURSIVA");
        break;

        case(AppConfig.BASTAO):
            rgLetterType.check(rbBastao.getId());

            Log.i("Json-Config","BASTAO");
        break;

        case(AppConfig.IMPRENSA):
            rgLetterType.check(rbImprensa.getId());

            Log.i("Json-Config","IMPRENSA");
        break;

    }

    switch(this.configurator.getCurrentLetterCase()){
        case(AppConfig.UPPER):
            rgLetterCase.check(rbUpper.getId());
            Log.i("Json-Config","UPPER");
        break;

        case(AppConfig.LOWER):
            rgLetterCase.check(rbLower.getId());
            Log.i("Json-Config","LOWER");
        break;

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Ja tentou seuTextView.setTypeface(Typeface.create("sans-serif-light", Typeface.NORMAL)); ?
Uma alternativa pra alterar todas fonts do textview do projeto, é criar uma subclasse que extende do Textview, usar um sharedpreference pra recuperar a configuração que o usuário colocou, e então retorná-la na sua custom textview. Acrescente seu código, que eu tento ajudar melhor.

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas amigo, vou tentar implementa-las. Sobre a persistência das configurações do usuário, estou usando JSON para salvar/recuperar, oque achas?

Comment: Eu criei uma classe AlphaTextView que estende de TextView, mas não sei como posso fazer para que todas as AlphaTextView que eu usar mudem ao alterar alguma das configurações que implementei na tela de configurações. Eu teria que, de alguma forma, ter uma lista de todas as AlphaTextViews usadas?

Comment: Vou fazer um aqui, utilizando sharedpreference ai você modifica pra usar com o Json que recebe. Daqui a pouco mando.

Comment: Pronto, eu subi o exemplo no github caso queira dar uma olhada. Qualquer coisa só perguntar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cria essa classe que irá extender de TextView:

```
public class NewTextView extends AppCompatTextView {
    private Context context;
    private String fontFamily;


    public NewTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        init();
    }

    public NewTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
        init();
    }

    public NewTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        this.context = context;
        init();
    }



    private void init() {
        //Eu criei sharedpreferences apenas para meu teste
        //No seu caso recupere os valores pelo seu próprio Json
        SharedPreferences preferences;
        preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(USER_FONTFAMILY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (preferences != null) {
            fontFamily = preferences.getString(FONTFAMILY, null);

            if (fontFamily != null) {
                switch (fontFamily) {
                    case CASUAL: {
                        Typeface tf = Typeface.create("sans-serif", Typeface.NORMAL);
                        setTypeface(tf);
                        break;
                    }
                    case CURSIVA: {
                        Typeface tf = Typeface.create("serif-monospace", Typeface.NORMAL);
                        setTypeface(tf);
                        break;
                    }
                    case BASTAO: {
                        Typeface tf = Typeface.create("sans-serif-smallcaps", Typeface.NORMAL);
                        setTypeface(tf);
                        break;
                    }

                }
            }
        } else {
            //default
            Typeface tf = Typeface.create("sans-serif", Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
            setTypeface(tf);
        }

    }
}
```

Ao invés do SharedPreference, você recupera a configuração do usuário pelo Json, nesse meu exemplo, usei sharedpreference apenas para testar mesmo.

Nos arquivos xmls que contém os textviews, altera TODOS eles para:

```
        <seupacotecompleto.NewTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/seuID"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Seu texto"/>
```

Caso queira ver o exemplo completo que eu fiz para testar, coloquei no meu github:

https://github.com/MurilloComino/ConfigTextviewFontFamily

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo, deu super certo!

Comment: Legal, qualquer dúvida no código só chamar, abraços

Answer (score 1):

Tem 2 formas de alterar o *fontFamily*:

- Usando o método `setTypeface()`:

  - `textView.setTypeface(Typeface.create("sans-serif-light", Typeface.NORMAL));`
  - `TextView.setTypeface(ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.YOUR_FONT));`
  - `TextView.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/mycustomfont.ttf"));`
- Usando o método `setTextAppearance()`:

  Crie um estilo por cada configuração e aplique-o ao TextView usando o método `setTextAppearance()`.

  *styles.xml*

  ```
  <style name="styleCausal">
      <item name="android:fontFamily">causal</item>
  </style>
  <style name="styleSans-serif">
      <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif</item>
  </style>
  ```

  *Java*

  ```
  if(isCausal){
      textView.setTextAppearance(R.style.styleCausal);
  }else{
      textView.setTextAppearance(R.style.styleSans-serif);
  }
  ```

O `setTextAppearance()` tem a vantagem de se poder declarar mais de uma característica ao mesmo tempo, usando `<item name=""></item>`.

Outra [forma de alterar/definir](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/266033/2541) a aparência do texto em toda a aplicação é usando temas.
Um determinado tema pode ser "setado" através de `setTheme()`. No entanto terá de ser feito no `onCreate()` e antes de `setContentView()`.